# Install gcc-9 on Coral Dev Board

Tags: google-coral, mendel-os

I want to install gcc-9 to run (E)XLA accelerated Linear Algebra on the CPU.
XLA requires `GLIBCXX_3.4.26` which is only available for gcc > 8.

Debians `testing` package source does not seem to work, since it cannot find gcc-9 either.